# How to prevent Googlebot from doing API requests?

Tags: google, web-crawlers, google-index, api

I have a currency converter site around 32k pages. Every pair for each page.
And every page has 2 API requests.

I started to see huge number of API requests. From users I have only few page views  because it is a new site.

I think that Google is crawling and making those requests.  How can I let Google crawl and index the page without doing API requests?

Comment: I have a similar currency conversion site.   API requests are not necessary for a currency conversion site.    Just put the currency data into JavaScript variables in the page.    Even if the currency data is available only as an API, you should be able to get it in one request.

Answer (score 1):

If the API is being hit on every page load there is no way to display the page without hitting the API.

As @Steve Ostenmier points out you can embed the conversion data in javascript which Google will still be able to parse but will only result in a single hit to the API if your API supports getting all of the conversion rates in a single request. Either way whatever you do it will require a change to the underlying code driving your site.

A good rule of thumb to follow is anything an end user can do without requiring a password can be done by Google and if it is done will likely be done orders of magnitude greater in a far shorter amount of time than a single or small group of end users can achieve themselves